# Website with dedicated IP Address, still uses shared server IP

Tags: server, ip, hosting, cpanel, dedicated-hosting

Using cPanel WHM I have created a website hosting with Dedicated IP Address,

I'm planning to use it with the IP Address instead of a domain (e.g. http://1.2.3.4/script.php)

It opens, script also works fine.

The only issue is the IP address it uses isn't dedicated, it still uses server's shared IP.

I checked by CURL equivalent file_get_contents('http://myip.is') , the IP is the shared IP of server not the IP is use in URL or dedicated to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of tries, I realized the issue is because of CURL, apparently it still uses the server's main IP Address.

I managed to fixed this by adding the following to my CURL function

```
// Changing 1.2.3.4 with websites real IP
$website_ip = '1.2.3.4';
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_INTERFACE, $website_ip);
```